# MapServer FastCGI connection pool configuration

Tags: postgresql, mapserver, connection

I posted this question in the [MapServer User mailing list](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/FastCGI-connection-pool-parameters-tt5486423.html) but hoping I can get more eyeballs on it here. I'll update both threads if I make any progress.

The [MapServer LAYER documentation](https://mapserver.org/fr/mapfile/layer.html#index-20) says the following on connection pooling in combination with FastCGI:

> Additionally, if you have FastCGI enabled, the connection handle will
> stay open indefinitely, or according to the options specified in the
> FastCGI configuration

I'm using MapServer with PostGIS and FastCGI, and I'm very interested in learning more about this, however I cannot find any information about how connection pooling should be configured in FastCGI.

Can anybody clarify here? How should connection pooling be controlled by FastCGI config?

Answer (score 1):

For MS4W users on Windows, I've created the documentation (https://ms4w.com/README_INSTALL.html#fastcgi) for FastCGI, which gives more specific examples, such as:

```
  <IfModule fcgid_module>
     FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0
     FcgidIdleScanInterval 1
     FcgidProcessLifeTime 10
  </IfModule>
```

and also points to the mod_fcgid page where each of these directives is defined in detail: https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html

Personally I always start with those settings, but others will have their favorite preferences for settings.

Hope that helps,

```
Jeff McKenna
@mapserving
```

Comment: How does this relate to connection pooling? Your first link describes how to set FastCGI directives and the second link describes FastCGI directives, but none of this seems to have anything to do with connection pooling??

Comment: Am I to understand that the connection persists for the life of the process, and by extension the life of the connection is managed through these process parameters?

Comment: Just curious, what is the benefit of scanning and killing the processes so quickly? And is the min processes set to 0 to save resources?